# How to convert Python decimal to SQLite numeric?

Tags: python, sqlite, decimal, numeric

I have a program that reads financial data in JSON and inserts it into an SQLite database.  The problem is when I'm inserting it into SQLite numeric column and it doesn't seem to like the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) object.

I've found this question [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801307/sqlite-and-python-floats/1801439#1801439), but the answer is outdated and from what I understand SQLite now has a currency data type [called numeric](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Right now as a workaround I'm storing decimal values as text, but is it possible to store it as numeric?  Am I stuck with the overhead of converting decimals to strings and vice versa for database inserts and financial calculations?

Comment: Use your own data type and use a BLOB type?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`sqlite3` allows you to register an adapter (to transparently convert `Decimals` to `TEXT` when inserting) and a converter (to transparently convert `TEXT` into `Decimals` when fetching).

The following is a lightly modified version of the example code from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#converting-sqlite-values-to-custom-python-types):

```
import sqlite3
import decimal
D=decimal.Decimal

def adapt_decimal(d):
    return str(d)

def convert_decimal(s):
    return D(s)

# Register the adapter
sqlite3.register_adapter(D, adapt_decimal)

# Register the converter
sqlite3.register_converter("decimal", convert_decimal)

d = D('4.12')

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table test(d decimal)")

cur.execute("insert into test(d) values (?)", (d,))
cur.execute("select d from test")
data=cur.fetchone()[0]
print(data)
print(type(data))

cur.close()
con.close()
```

yields

```
4.12
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

Comment: This solution no longer works. As per the sqlite3 documentation, converter functions are always called in `bytes` format, so in order for the code to work in Python 3.8, you must call `D(s.decode('utf-8'))` on the definition of the `convert_decimal` function.

Comment: @manoelpqueiroz since a Decimal has only ASCII characters I would use the ASCII encoding, i.e. `D(s.decode('ascii'))` because it's a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Using a name such as DECTEXT for the column type, which would be considered a text type, alows you to properly create aggregate functions. With the name *decimal*, sqlite3  would try to convert a decimal column to a float prior to calling the aggregate function class's 'step' method. See [this example](https://ideone.com/qAWSPI).

Answer (score 4):

The [column affinity rules for SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity) say:

> If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings
> "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice
> that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned
> TEXT affinity.

You can declare columns to be any type you like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a_test(
  a_decimal DECTEXT NOT NULL  -- will be stored as TEXT
);
```

---

```python
def adapt_decimal(d):
    return str(d)

def convert_decimal(s):
    return decimal.Decimal(s)

# Register the adapter
sqlite3.register_adapter(decimal.Decimal, adapt_decimal)

# Register the converter
sqlite3.register_converter("DECTEXT", convert_decimal)

con = sqlite3.connect("test.s3db", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
C1 = con.cursor()

C1.execute("INSERT INTO a_test VALUES(?)", (decimal.Decimal("102.20"),))
```

Don't know if this is a good way to handle it or not - comments welcome

Comment: In my opinion, this is better than the accepted answer since it allows you to create aggregate functions such as `decimal_sum` that will sum a column using decimal math. Without explicitly using a type such as DECTEXT that is understood to be a text column, sqlite3 would first try to convert the stored value to a float. See this [example code](https://ideone.com/qAWSPI).

Answer (score 3):

I found that I had to make a small tweak to unutbu's [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6319513). With a modified example with a value '4.00', it comes back out of the database as '4'. I'm dealing with commodities and don't want to hardcode the precision into the database (like I'd be doing if I just multiplied and divided by 100). So I tweaked the conversion functions as follows:

```
def adapt_decimal(d):
    return '#'+str(d)

def convert_decimal(s):
    return D(s[1:])
```

which isn't aesthetically great but does defeat sqlite's eagerness to store the field as an integer and lose track of the precision.

Answer (score 1):

At least the page you linked to didn't mention a `currency` data type, and the [`decimal(10,5)` example datatype](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname) simply turns on the `NUMERIC` affinity.

If it were my data, I'd probably store an integer number of currency "units" -- pennies, or tenths of a penny, or hundredths of a penny, whatever is appropriate -- and then use a *scaling factor* to turn the integer input into the decimal equivalent to compute with when reading data from the database. It's harder to screw up with integers.

Comment: Isn't that what was mentioned in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801307/sqlite-and-python-floats/1801319#1801319)?

Comment: @William, yes, it's far from a new idea. :) Just be sure to set the scaling parameter large enough for your application. `2` might be enough for accounting for a small business, but you might need `3`, `4`, or `5` or more depending upon currency conversions, or interest rate calculations, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am basically following the same approach as others but with one addition. The problem is that defining an adapter and converter takes care of the case of when you are accessing decimal columns row by row. But when you issue an aggregate function, such as summing a decimal column across all rows, the summation is done using real (i.e. floating point arithmetic) and the returned result will be a float with subsequent rounding errors.

The solution is to create a custom-tailored aggregate function, *decimal_sum*. Since *sqlite3* aggregate functions are constrained in the types that they may return, *decimal_sum* will return a string representation of the decimal sum, which will be case to a *Decimal* type (this code is also Python 3-compatible):

```py
import sqlite3
from decimal import Decimal


# DECTEXT columns will have TEXT affinity:
sqlite3.register_adapter(Decimal, lambda d: str(d))
sqlite3.register_converter("DECTEXT", lambda d: Decimal(d.decode('ascii')))


class DecimalSum:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = None

    def step(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return
        v = Decimal(value)
        if self.sum is None:
            self.sum = v
        else:
            self.sum += v

    def finalize(self):
        return None if self.sum is None else str(self.sum)


conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
conn.create_aggregate("decimal_sum", 1, DecimalSum)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
    create table test (
        amount DECTEXT not null
    )
""")

for _ in range(1000):
    cursor.execute("insert into test(amount) values(?)", (Decimal("12.01"),))
conn.commit()

# Uses floating point math:
cursor.execute("select sum(amount) from test")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print('Floating point sum:', row[0], type(row[0]))

# Uses decimal math but returns result as a string
# and so we do a final conversion from string to Decimal:
cursor.execute("select decimal_sum(amount) as `amount [dectext]` from test")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print('Decimal sum:', row[0], type(row[0]))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Prints:

```None
Floating point sum: 12010.000000000178 <class 'float'>
Decimal sum: 12010.00 <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```