# SQLAlchemy query raises unnecessary warning about sqlite and Decimal, how to specifically disable?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using SQLAlchemy via pyramid accessing a simple sqlite database.

As I was building my progressively more complex queries, I got this warning:-

SAWarning: Dialect sqlite+pysqlite does *not* support Decimal objects natively, and SQLAlchemy must convert from floating point - rounding errors and other issues may occur. Please consider storing Decimal numbers as strings or integers on this platform for lossless storage.

One of my queries does this (paraphrasing):-

```
session.query(subquery.c.a*100.0/(subquery.c.b+subquery.c.c))
```

In this case, subquery is the name of a subquery, and a, b, and c are integers.

I'm not saving the result of the query or running any commits, this is purely data extraction/querying, hence I was surprised when the warning above was raised. How do I ignore this warning without filtering it out totally (in case in future I do accidentally save Decimal data to the database)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ignore [warnings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) with [`warnings.filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) as done [here](https://rattailproject.org/klaus/rattail/commit/a2b13de31c61a2e4f74b814647156ed0cd8de0ee/):

```
import warnings
from sqlalchemy.exc import SAWarning
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore',
 r"^Dialect sqlite\+pysqlite does \*not\* support Decimal objects natively\, "
 "and SQLAlchemy must convert from floating point - rounding errors and other "
 "issues may occur\. Please consider storing Decimal numbers as strings or "
 "integers on this platform for lossless storage\.$",
 SAWarning, r'^sqlalchemy\.sql\.type_api$')
```

**Edit:** The problem of using decimal values with SQLite and SQLAlchemy is already discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355767/how-should-i-handle-decimal-in-sqlalchemy-sqlite), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386911/1771479) suggests to create [`TypeDecorator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#typedecorator-recipes) that stores the decimal values internally as text.

For the division by 100.0 in your query it seems that this value is converted to [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) by SQLAlchemy. However you can create a [`literal_column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) with 100.0 as value:

```
import sqlalchemy
val100 = sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column("100.0")
session.query(subquery.c.a*val100/(subquery.c.b+subquery.c.c))
```

When using this solution it does not show a warning for me.

<sup>P.D.: I use SQLAlchemy version 1.0.11, and Python 2.7.11.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but my final sentence was "How do I ignore this warning **without filtering it out totally** (in case in future I do accidentally save Decimal data to the database)?

Comment: At the moment of writing, sqlalchemy 1.2.10 has the type not in `type_api`, but in `sqltypes`, also the regex didn't work for me. For me this worked: `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', r".*support Decimal objects natively", SAWarning, r'^sqlalchemy\.sql\.sqltypes$')`

Answer (score 2):

this works for me (as of 11.11.2023)

```
import warnings
from sqlalchemy.exc import SAWarning

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", r".*support Decimal objects natively, and SQLAlchemy", SAWarning)
```